# How can I give my box another background-color on hover?

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/azt1kztr/

```
<a href="www.google.de">
  <li>
    <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:pink">
    hallo
    </div>
  </li>
</a>

<style>
a:hover{background-color:blue}
</style>
```

Why does my box not become red on hover?

Comment: Because your div's inline style is superimposing your `:hover` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the background  color of the anchor tag.. Change the background of the div.. Try this

`a:hover div{background-color:blue}`

Also another option you can directly add Hover effect to div like this.

`div:hover{background-color:blue}`

Answer (score 1):

> Why does my box not become red on hover?

The link does get red background on hover – you just don’t *see* any of it, because your link is only as wide and high as the content demands – and that content itself has a pink background covering everything.

Make your `a` element `display:block`, then you’ll see the blue background *next* to the div element.

Or, if you want to actually change the background of the div element, don’t set the initial background using the `style` attribute, but via a CSS rule as well – and then use the descendant selector:

```
a:hover div { … }
```

And FYI, you are creating invalid HTML – `li` can only be a child of a list element (ul/ol), not a child of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have invalid HTML syntax there, you cannot nest your `li` element as a direct child to any other element except for `ul`.

As far as your hover goes, it won't work as you are using inline styles to apply a background to your `div` element. Also, you are writing a selector which is targeting `a` tag instead of `div`

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/azt1kztr/3/)

```
a:hover div {
  /* the dirty way, read ahead for the right way */
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

---

**BUT**, I won't recommend you the above solution. The correct way to do is to use `ul` and nest your `li` inside the `ul` and than, take out your inline styles and move to a stylesheet. Later, apply hover styles on the intended element you want to. Also, nest your list inside the wrapper div.

Right way to achieve your goal :

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/azt1kztr/4/)

Make sure you use classes on your wrapper `div`, am just using `div {}` and `div:hover {}` for demo purpose only.